# How to identify whether a file is elf file using C language function？

Tags: c, linux, elf

In my program , I want to identify whether a file  is ELF(Executable and Linkable Format) type.   How to  identify whether a file is elf file using C language function?

Comment: The shell commands `file <file name>` gives you this information. So, you can use this shell command in your `C` program using:

    `execv("/path/to/file-cmd", args);`

Comment: @brokenfoot, if you are going to parse the output of `file`, you might as well parse the elf header.  It's easier.  Or use `libmagic`, which I think is what `file` uses.

Answer (score 14):

If the **only** thing you want to do is test whether the file is ELF or not, then read the first 16 bytes to check the file identity.  The first four bytes will equal `{0x7f, 'E', 'L', 'F'}`.  The remaining bytes can vary, but checking them will help you be even more certain that the file is elf.  See the [elf(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/elf) man page for more detail.

That man page gives enough info for parsing ELF files in general, but if you want to do more than just check the format, then you should probably use a library.  See both [the Elf Toolchain](http://sourceforge.net/p/elftoolchain/wiki/Home/) and [the Binary File Descriptor Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_File_Descriptor_library).

**Update:**  Yet another alternative is [libmagic(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic) which will read the ELF header for you.  It is probably overkill if you are only interested in ELF, but libmagic also knows about just about every file format worth knowing about.